# How to write in json file in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with data

```
{
  "Theme": "dark_background"
}
```

I am using below code to read the value of Theme

```
    import json
    with open("setting.json", "r") as f:
        stuff = json.load(f)
        f.close()
    style = stuff['Theme']
```

Now i want to write/change the value of Theme, How to do that?

Comment: It's just a normal Python dictionary.  You change it like you would any Python dictionary.  When you're done making your changes, you use `json.dump` to write it back out to the file.

Comment: `stuff['Theme'] = 'something else'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To serialize an object (list, dictionary, etc.) in Python to the JSON format use the json library with either the [json.dump()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) or [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function. The function `json.dump()` formats to a stream and `json.dumps()` returns a formatted JSON string.

```python
import json

with open("setting.json", "r") as f:
    stuff = json.load(f)
style = stuff.get("Theme")
print("old:", style)

# set new value in dictionary
stuff["Theme"] = "light_background"
print("new:", stuff["Theme"])

# write JSON output to file
with open("setting.json", "w") as fout:
    json.dump(stuff, fout)
```

**Output:**

```
old: dark_background
new: light_background
```

To pretty-print the JSON output use the *indent* argument.

```
with open("setting.json", "w") as fout:
    json.dump(stuff, fout, indent=4)
```